# R: use single file while running a for loop on list of files

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am trying to create a loop where I select one file name from a list of file names, and use that one file to run `read.capthist` and subsequently `discretize`, `fit`, `derived`, and save the outputs using `save`. The list contains 10 files of identical rows and columns, the only difference between them are the geographical coordinates in each row.

The issue I am running into is that `capt` needs to be a single file (in the `secr` package they are 'captfile' types), but I don't know how to select a single file from this list and get my loop to recognize it as a single entity.

This is the error I get when I try and select only one file:

```
Error in read.capthist(female[[i]], simtraps, fmt = "XY", detector = "polygon") : 
  requires single 'captfile'
```

I am not a programmer by training, I've learned R on my own and used stack overflow a lot for solving my issues, but I haven't been able to figure this out. Here is the code I've come up with so far:

```
library(secr)
setwd("./")
files = list.files(pattern = "female*")
lst <- vector("list", length(files))
names(lst) <- files
for (i in 1:length(lst)) {
  capt <- lst[i]
  femsimCH <- read.capthist(capt, simtraps, fmt = 'XY', detector = "polygon")
  femsimdiscCH <- discretize(femsimCH, spacing = 2500, outputdetector = 'proximity')
  fit <- secr.fit(femsimdiscCH, buffer = 15000, detectfn = 'HEX', method = 'BFGS', trace = FALSE, CL = TRUE)
  save(fit, file="C:/temp/fit.Rdata")
  D.fit <- derived(fit)
  save(D.fit, file="C:/temp/D.fit.Rdata")
}
```

`simtraps` is a list of coordinates.

Ideally I would also like to have my outputs have unique identifiers as well, since I am simulating data and I will have to compare all the results, I don't want each iteration to overwrite the previous data output.

I know I can use this code by bringing in each file and running this separately (this code works for non-simulation runs of a couple data sets), but as I'm hoping to run 100 simulations, this would be laborious and prone to mistakes.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated for an R novice!

Comment: What's lst for?

Comment: I was working off of another help question on stack overflow that was similar and I saw that - but it could be that I'm adding components I don't need.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `read.capthist`, so I won't suggest a full answer, but I would start with removing the `lst` line, and replacing the for loop with: `for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  capt <- files[i]`...